# What is the meaning of flake8 (python linter) markings of different colors? Can I change those marking for specific warnings?

Tags: python, warnings, flake8, linter

In my .py files I have wavy-underlines of three colors: red, yellow and blue. And I have $ flake8 --version:

```
> 4.0.1 (flake8-bugbear: 21.11.29, mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.8.0, pyflakes: 2.4.0)
 CPython 3.8.10 on Linux
```

Looking at Pylance's python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides optinon, I think it explains (more or less) difference between those colors for flake8 too:

```
error (red squiggle)
warning (yellow squiggle)
information (blue squiggle)
```

Right? Or is it not? Thought "bugbear" calls B015 a warning, but underline it with blue squiggle, why? So can we change this "Pointless comparison.flake8(B015)" to be yellow or red and not blue?

At https://pypi.org/project/flake8-bugbear/ it is called "Warnings", but it is underlined with blue squiggle as pylance's "information".

Comment: the F / E / W / B prefixes don't indicate their severity -- just the plugin that they came from.  they **do not** stand for "fatal" "error" "warning", etc. - the current flake8 maintainer

Comment: @AnthonySottile Thanks. So does it means that there no way to set them in some settings or ini file, but I should just type "import bugbear", ctrl+click it and change bugbear plugin itself, to make B015 into warning or error?

Comment: But that will fail after modules updates. Is writing my own module for this only option or can I change some settings and make it work. And is it really that B015 is underlined with blue squiggle because it is informational? Cause it's docs say's it is warning, not information.

Comment: whatever plugin is making the squiggles is misinterpreting the error code prefix (a common mistake) -- I'd try and track down whatever plugin that is and get them to adjust the behaviour